# Should SoapFaults be encrypted when using ws-security

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, ws-security

I am attempting to consume a web service from Apache CXF and it is erroring because the soapfault is not encrypted.  I would like to inspect the soapfault and give a more descriptive error message.  Should the web service I am consuming encrypt the soapfault?  Can CXF be configured to consume a web service that throws unencrypted soapfaults?